# How can I send data to this Laravel form via AJAX?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-8

I am making a Laravel 8 app with *posts* and *post categories*. I am now working on the *Edit post* form, and I need to prepopulate it with the post's current data.

The `id` column in the `catergories` table is the `category_id` foreign key in the `posts` table.

In the **Posts model** I have:

```
class Posts extends Model {
   use HasFactory;
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'category_id',
        'description',
        'body'
    ];
}
```

The route is `Route::get('/dashboard/posts/edit/{id}', [PostsController::class, 'editPost'])`.

The `editPost` method in the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Posts;

class PostsController extends Controller {

    // More code

    public function editPost($id) {

        $post = Posts::select (
            "posts.id",
            "posts.title",
            "posts.description",
            "posts.body",
            "catergories.name as category_name"
            )
            ->leftJoin("catergories", "posts.category_id", "=", "catergories.id")
            ->where('posts.id', $id)
            ->first();

            echo $post->title . '<br>';
            echo $post->category_name . '<br>';
    }
}
```

In the form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="post_id" value="">

<div class="form-group mb-2 @error('title') has-error @enderror"> 
        <label for="title" class="text-muted">Title</label>       
        <input id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" value="{{ old('title', $post->title) }}" class="form-control @error('title') is-invalid @enderror" autofocus>

        @error('title')<span class="error-msg">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
    </div>

    <div class="form-group mb-2 @error('category_id') has-error @enderror">
        <label for="category" class="text-muted">Category</label>
        <select name="category_id" id="category" class="form-control @error('category_id') is-invalid @enderror">
            <option value="0">Select a category</option>
            @foreach($categorys as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}" {{ $category->id == $post->category_id  ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                    {{ $category->name }}
                </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
</div>
```

#### The goal

The form is placed in a Bootstrap 5 modal, which means that I can not access `https://myapp.test/dashboard/posts/edit/1` to get the necessary data. I have to do this via AJAX.

For this purpose, I have the following JavaScript function

```
function populateEditForm(event, entity) {
    var id = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    var url = `/dashboard/${entity}/edit/${id}`;
    console.log(url);

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) { 
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    console.log(xmlhttp.responseURL);
                }
            }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

that I call in a Blade template:

```
<a onclick="populateEditForm(event, 'posts')" href="#" data-id="{{ $post->id }}" title="Edit post" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#edit_post_modal">
        <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
</a>
```

#### The problem

The console *corectly* displays the path to the edit method in the controller: `https://myapp.test/dashboard/posts/edit/1` (for the post with id equal to 1), but I don't know how to use this to get the necessary data ( `$post->title`, `$post->category_name`, etc) and pass it to the form.

###### What is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the response as JSON and repopulate the form.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Posts;

class PostsController extends Controller {

    // More code

    public function editPost($id) {

        $post = Posts::select (
            "posts.id",
            "posts.title",
            "posts.description",
            "posts.body",
            "catergories.name as category_name"
            )
            ->leftJoin("catergories", "posts.category_id", "=", "catergories.id")
            ->where('posts.id', $id)
            ->first();

           return response()->json(['post' => $post]);
    }
}
```

In your JavaScript

```
function populateEditForm(event, entity) {
    var id = event.currentTarget.dataset.id;
    var url = `/dashboard/${entity}/edit/${id}`;
    console.log(url);

    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) { 
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    console.log(xmlhttp.response);
                }
            }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: What about the form, how how do I populate it with data?

Comment: You need to change the value of each input with the desired data, for example 
document.querySelector("#name").value = 'John Doe'
This will update this input's value by it's id assuming that the element with id name is an input.

Comment: In your case your response is there you just have to figure out what to put where. You can also use xmlhttp.responseText instead of xmlhttp.response, check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseText